# How do I determine in python if an external program is open?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to determine in python if a certain application is already open so that I don't open it twice. I've done a little research and have found that it is possible to pull the process name of a program, but the only issue I have with that is the program I am checking for itself has a pretty generic process name (in this case, "pythonw.exe" or "cmd.exe").

It does however have differing names in the application list of Windows Task Manager, so my question is if there is any way to use that to detect if a program is open or not. My workplace will not allow me to download additional programs or modules to use for this script, so the answer needs to use the os module or something similar that is already included in the windows library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Python standard modules can't finish your requirement. It need some 3rd party libs, like `win32api`, `win32pdhutil`, `win32con`.

Another approach is using windows command `tasklist`. Use Python as the bat wrapper, and parse the output of `tasklist`.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>tasklist

Image Name                   PID Session Name     Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ====== ================ ======== ============
System Idle Process            0 Console                 0         28 K
System                         4 Console                 0        236 K
smss.exe                     812 Console                 0        388 K
csrss.exe                    860 Console                 0      3,720 K
winlogon.exe                 884 Console                 0      4,148 K
services.exe                 928 Console                 0      3,356 K
lsass.exe                    940 Console                 0      5,904 K
vmacthlp.exe                1100 Console                 0      2,348 K
...
```

Comment: +1 for the tasklist command, windows user for several years in i never knew this.

Comment: This is a useful command, it is a shame though that the PID isn't consistent enough to pull a specific program. Thanks for the information though; better to know it is something I can't do (without additional libraries) than to run around trying to find an answer that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9):

I use the following code to check if a certain program is running:

```
import psutil     #psutil - https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

# Get a list of all running processes
list = psutil.pids()

# Go though list and check each processes executeable name for 'putty.exe'
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    try:
        p = psutil.Process(list[i])
        if p.cmdline()[0].find("putty.exe") != -1:
            # PuTTY found. Kill it
            p.kill()
            break;
    except:
        pass
```

PS: You can install your own modules using [Virtual ENV](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) or just choose an alternative installation path!

Comment: Thanks, but the code has to be run on machines other than mine without an additional installer, hence why I can't use additional modules.

Comment: If you really want to remove dependencies wouldn't you want to use py2exe or a similar program?